# Hide Part of URL htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The Goal:

1. The user lands on the site where the latest 10 articles are shown (no problem here).
2. The user clicks on the title of one article using this `href` link in a table:

   `<a href='"."article.php/".$type."/".$id."/".$web_title."'>".$title."</a>`
3. All links from any `$type` get directed to `article.php`.
4. `article.php` should be built dynamically based on the `$id` retrieving information from the database.

I've got this URL rewrite in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/article/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ article.php?post_type=$1&post_id=$2&post_name=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Which is producing the URL: `http://example.org/article.php/news/1/first-article-test` when the user accesses `article.php` via a link described in point 2.

I'm trying to remove the `article.php` section from the above URL, so it looks just like this:
`http://example.org/news/1/first-article-test`

At the moment the `article.php` page is receiving the variables just fine, it's pulling down other data from the database based on the `$id` passed by the link, but the URL is displaying `article.php/...`.

Comment: You are capturing only one value but using `$1`, `$2`, `$3`etc...

Comment: How so? - the page is extracting them fine and getting values from the DB based on them, what should I be doing?

Comment: I can't say but `^(.*)$` captures and populates `$1` only.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "producing"... the end result of your rewrite is `article.php?post_type=[ENTIRE MATCHED URL]&post_id=[BLANK]&post_name=[BLANK]`.  Your first `RewriteCond` ensures that your desired URL will match it.

Comment: I am suspecting your rewrite rule isn't firing at all. You can comment it out and retest.

Comment: @anubhava oh dang its not firing at all, the URL still comes out like in the example above, but the article.php page doesn't get populated by my PHP function if i remove it, is there any way i can change it to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/article\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /article.php/$1 [L]
```

It will let you have your links as

```
http://example.org/news/1/first-article-test
```

Comment: My index.php won't load properly when I use that, the images and PHP includes stop working, article.php and index.php are both in the same directory

Comment: This won't affect `index.php` but for css/images just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: I've got an external php file called article_functions.php, are your htaccess rules stopping it from being called? (i'm pretty newbie at htaccess)

Comment: No it should not. Open your request in Firebug and see which URLs are causing 404?