# How to remove (not hide) a subdirectory from a URL using .htacesss

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a series of URLs on my website:

http://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/content.html

But I would like to remove "sub1" completely - not hide it so it still attempts to access that directory. Finished result would be this URL:

http://www.example.com/sub2/content.html

Many similar posts on SE seem to demonstrate how to "hide" a URL from the user. I want to rewrite the URL so that it treats it as if it isn't even there.

Example of what I'm trying *not* to do: [Hide Part of URL htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041964/hide-part-of-url-htaccess)

NOTE: I do not want to actually delete files as suggested by the comment below. I'm trying to *redirect* the request to another directory.

Comment: `.htaccess` doesn't modify the files and directories on disk. It only changes the way they map to URLs. If you want to remove `sub1` and make the first URL invalid then you can move sub-directory `sub2` one level up then remove `sub1` if it became empty. You can also use the advice from the linked answer and forbid the access to `/sub1/sub2` to "delete" `sub2".

Comment: Forgive my phrasing, I want to "redirect" http://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/content.html to pull from http://www.example.com/sub1/content.html.

Comment: Redirection is easier. Just add [`RedirectPermanent /sub1/sub2 /sub2`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) to `.htaccess` and enjoy.

Comment: Last question: Will sub1/sub2/content.html redirect to sub2/content.html or will it default just the directory /sub2 without trailing content?

Comment: You have two ways to find out: read the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) or try it and see how it works. Or, even better, do both.

Comment: If everyone read the documentation there wouldn't be a need for StackOverflow. Then we wouldn't be having this conversation. Then we would have never been able to share this conversation.

Comment: The documentation tells you how the things work. Stackoverflow tells you how others think that the things work. Too many times the answers on Stackoverflow are wrong or perform badly because neither the ones who ask nor the ones who answer didn't bother to check the documentation.

Comment: Your answer, for example, is not optimal. It requires the [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) extension which is not loaded by default by Apache. `RedirectPermanent` is a directive of the [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) module which is part of the Apache core (i.e. it is always available). More, even if `mod_rewrite` is available, the rewriting requires more work than the [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directives

Comment: Thanks, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

RewriteRule ^sub1/sub2/(.*)$ /sub2/$1 [R=302,NC,L]

Helpful page: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/